# Failed to resolve dependencies (Grails/Spring)

Tags: grails, dependencies

I'm trying to run a new Grails project and i get this error

```
    | Configuring classpath
    | Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
    - org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.4.RELEASE
    - org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.4.RELEASE
    - org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.4.RELEASE
    - org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.4.RELEASE
    - org.springframework:spring-aspects:3.2.4.RELEASE
    - org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
    - org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
    - org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.4.RELEASE
    - org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.4.RELEASE
    - org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.4.RELEASE
    - org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.4.RELEASE
    - org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.7.2
    - asm:asm:3.3.1
    - org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.7.2
    - cglib:cglib:2.2.2
    - org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.4.RELEASE
    - org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.4.RELEASE
```

and i'm using the sts IDE... what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the STS issue - one advice I have is to try to get grails run-app running in the command prompt.  That should download all the dependencies correctly onto your file system, and then hopefully STS will pick those up as well.